# ParseFloat String Java

Tags: java

I have this String -> "100,24" and I want join in the var Java type float

But when I have the parse, I get error.

```
article.cost((Float.parseFloat(array.get(y))));
```

I need help, ty.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Please rephrase the question so it makes sense, and include any error messages.

Comment: The decimal symbol should be `.`

Comment: Error is For input string: . In my country "Decimal" is with ","

Comment: @EduBw that's why I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number format must contain dot(`.`) instead of comma(`,`). That's why you get the exception. However, you can also use `parseFloat` with String's `replace` method to convert float by using comma.

```
class NumberTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String y = "100,24";
        float num = Float.parseFloat(y.replace(',','.'));
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's correct, very thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the comma, "100,24", that string is not a valid float. So an error will be thrown if you try converting it to one. However if this is what you intended "100.24" that should fix your problem, because that is a valid float type.

So what you do is replace the ',' with a '.' and then try converting. i.e.

```
String floatStr = "100,24".replace(",", "."); // Change to a correct float value
float newFloat = Float.parse(floatStr); // parse and get your new float
```